# Using swift URLImage package with nil objects

Tags: json, swift, networking

I am using a News API to retrieve news articles however, occasionally the imageURL is nil. When this happens, the URLImage package cannot load in the relevant image and nothing on the app loads in.

Can someone please tell me how I can use some sort of optionals to have a default image for if the imageURL is not present.

OR

Not load in the row of the list entirely if it does not fit certain criteria such as having a nil value for the imageURL

Above is the code that loads in the view.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // for every single post in the post array
        List(networkManager.posts) { post in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: post.url)) {
                VStack {
                    Text(post.title)
                        .bold()
                    HStack {
                        Text(post.description ?? "No description provided.")
                            .padding(.top)
                        // Check the url of the image
                        URLImage(URL(string: post.urlToImage)!) { proxy in
                            proxy.image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                        .frame(width:150)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Science Bite")
    }
        // This calls fetch data
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you need to see more of my code to solve the problem, here is the link to my GitHub repository. [Github Link](https://github.com/ParisJacksonNewman/ScienceBite)

Very sorry for any inconvenience as this is my first ever project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I solved the problem by moving the UIImage code into another struct into (optionally) another file. I then added an initialiser for the unwrapped option string of the urlToImage and a computed property for a new string that is not an optional by using optional binding.

Here is the code:

```
struct URLImageView: View {

let badURL: String?

var imgURL: String {
    if let safeURL = badURL {
        return safeURL
    } else {
        return "https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/s-jZTk0XtVmp-89MlOgFXqaAVe4=/fit-in/1600x0/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/29/0f/290fb8c0-1872-46e5-8c12-235742905def/science_smithsonian_magazine_booklist_2019.png"
    }
}

var body: some View {
    URLImage(URL(string: imgURL)!) { proxy in
        proxy.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
    .frame(width: 150)
}
```

I then added this struct into my main content view with the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        // for every single post in the post array
        List(networkManager.posts) { post in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: post.url)) {
                VStack {
                    Text(post.title)
                        .bold()
                    HStack {
                        Text(post.description ?? "No description provided")
                            .padding(.top)
                        // Check the url of the image
                        URLImageView(badURL: post.urlToImage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Science Bite")
    }
        // This calls fetch data
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help anyone with a similar problem.